# res.sendFile inside of ejs template

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'd like to use `res.sendFile()` **inside** an .ejs template in express.

```
<%
    //current media
    var cm = page.data.media;    
    cm = cm || {};
    var file = cm.file || {};
    var ext = cm.thumbnail_url.substr(cm.thumbnail_url.lastIndexOf("."));

    var options = {
        root: __root,
        dotfiles: 'deny',
        headers: {
            'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
            'x-sent': true
        }
    };

    res.sendFile("uploads/thmb/media/" + cm._id.toString() + ext, options);
    res.end();
%>
```

But in my server.js that handles the request i use `res.render('media.ejs')` torender the above .ejs file.

So that results in:

```
[Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.]
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

this seems to be because res.render does already sent some information on the response object. Is it possible if i use an ejs template to instead just send a file ?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to run that code from an EJS template instead of from your route handler directly? It seems like you're trying to fit a PHP-like paradigm on top of Express.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? I don't even know how that would work. Are you sending down a template or a file? Make up your mind.

Comment: That is kind of complicated. Let's say everthing works generic in the application, and i can only change the .ejs template. When the url /myapp/media/1234556 is called in want to deliver an image but the ejs template media.ejs is automacially rendered and populated with information.